# Write mockito unit test for Firebase Authentication kotlin compose

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mockito, android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to perform a unit test on Firebase Auth functionality

Here's the service I have:

```
open class AuthService(private val auth: FirebaseAuth) {
     suspend fun createUser(email: String, password: String, onTask: (Throwable?) -> Unit) {
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener{onTask(it.exception)}.await()
    }
    suspend fun logInUser(email: String, password: String, onTask: (Throwable?) -> Unit) {
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener{onTask(it.exception)}.await()
    }
}
```

What would be the code to unit test this service with the help of mockito?

Comment: Can you post your attempts?